# Index versus Index, Follow

Tags: html, seo

Me respondam uma dúvida. Qual é a diferença entre

`<meta name="robots" content="index, follow">`  e

```
<meta name="robots" content="index">
```

É a mesma coisa ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Não, não são. Uma complementa a outra mas são diferentes.

**Index**: utilizada para dizer que a página deve ser indexada, que deve aparecer nas páginas de busca;

**Follow**: utilizada para dizer que os links da página deve ser seguidos para tentar buscar outras paginas dentro do conteúdo da página atual.

Sendo assim, você pode usar, o outro, ou os dois.